# Return string (64 chars) to another contract in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, string, data-types

I have two contracts :

```
contract Child {

      mapping(string => string) private strings;


      function GetString(string key) public constant returns(string value) {
        return strings[key];
      }

}


contract Parent {

     Child c;


     function GetString(string key) public constant returns(string value) {
         return c.GetString(key);
     }

 }
```

I got a compilation error :

```
Return argument type is not implicitly convertible to expected type
```

I think this is a restriction of solidity that a contract cannot read a variable-sized data that is returned by another contract

Since my string can have more than 32 chars (i cannot use the `bytes32` type), how can i achieve that ?

Thanks for your help !

MC

Answer (score 4):

*For now*, it's not possible to pass strings between contracts.

I would *consider* chopping the string up into two bytes32 chunks. It would be more gas-efficient.

Web3 clients are better suited to pack/unpack/convert. *In my opinion*, it's *usually* best to transfer the burden of data type conversion to clients.

Hope it helps.

Comment: please confirm if this is possible today, post Metropolis Hard Fork

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it's a compiler limitation and it's still true. In practice, I haven't made any variation of the above successfully compile at solc 0.4.20. Possibly someone will chime in if there's a way.